# Textarea resizing when scrolling

Tags: ionic-framework

When scrolling a view with a textarea, the text area changes height while scrolling. After scrolling the original height is restored. This happens both in the Chrome device emulator and on iOS/Safari. See video for example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMYaScyFL74

This example is based on the tabs example application

```
   <ion-content class="padding">

      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Write something then scroll the view while the textarea is focued"></textarea>
        </label>
      </div>

    </ion-content>
```

Note that you have to enable the device emulator in Chrome to reproduce the problem. You can find the full source here: 
http://codepen.io/moberg/pen/myyYMJ

Anyone knows how to make the textarea preserve its size while scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1934

A fix seems to be ready to be merged atm: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/pull/3007